# Direct Update with custom URL not working on iOS 7.1.2

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

Since my upgrade to WL 6.2 direct update isn't working anymore on iOS.
What I'm trying to achieve is to get direct update working with the iPad and my windows machine. This way I can develop on my windows machine and use direct update to push my changes to the iPad (iOS 7.1.2). Following scenario describes my problem.

Create a new WL project in worklight studio on Mac (just installed the latest WL plugin today (platformVersion=6.2.0.00.20140724-2139). Add iOS as environment and replace the main.js with the following code:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
        onFailure: onConnectFailure
    });
}

function onConnectSuccess() {
    WL.Logger.debug("Connect success.");
}

function onConnectFailure() {
    WL.Logger.debug("Connect failed.");
}
```

Run the project as an Xcode project and use Xcode to deploy the application to an iPad. Now follow the following steps to reproduce the issue:

1. Make a modification in the index.html
2. Redeploy the app on your local worklight server in eclipse
3. Kill your app and restart it again
4. The direct update is working and your changes are reflected in your app. Yeah!

Now as a very basic next step, try to use the direct update with a Custom Server URL. Thick the **Use custom URL checkbox** in your iPad settings and change the Custom server URL to the URL of your local server.

[image: Change Server Connectivity Settings]

When I now retry step 1 to 3, the direct update fails. On startup the app informs me an update is available, and when I click update the downloading progress bar appears but stays at 0% forever. In the custom server URL I only changed the IP to the IP of my macbook and removed the dash after the project name. I also tried changing the URL to the URL of my windows development machine (also with the latest WL eclipse plugin), but this results in the same behaviour.

One last remark; I would expect that when I disable the Use custom URL checkbox; direct update would work again. But this is not the case.

Comment: The problem here is the dash mark which is removed after the project name.Because whenever you deploy the application to the server,it can understand something is altered in your application and its pushed as direct update to the device (or) emulator.But your client cant know where to load the web-resources i.e("Source").This is purely my assumption just try it with the / at the end of the URL.

Comment: Kawinesh, when I add the dash after the project name and retry I come in the onFailure handler. This was also the case when I was teting with 6.1, however when I removed the dash in 6.1 things would work just fine. Just to be clear; this is how my custom URL looks like: [http://172.17.22.50:10080/HelloWorld](http://www.google.be)

Comment: When you say "change the server URL", this implies to me that you have an external server. Correct? If so, after building the app with the new resources, do you also take the .wlapp file and deploy to that server URL to which you point your app in the device to by changing the server URL?

Comment: Idan, I don't have an external server. I just want to do a basic test and connect to my local eclipse server on my development machine (mac) with a custom server URL. The next test is to use the direct update with my local eclipse server on my windows development machine. This way I don't need to switch each time to the mac if I want to test a new version of the app on the iPad. This was working in WL 6.1.

Comment: But it already receives a URL. I don't understand what do you mean then by changing it to a custom URL. I suggest for you to edit the question with complete step-by-step instructions to help and reproduce your issue.

Comment: Idan, I have edited my question. When I say 'Changing it to a custom URL', I mean modifying the Custom server URL in the iOS settings for your WL application. I added a screenshot in my question to clarify this.

Comment: So you didn't actually modify it to any OTHER Server URL. Rather, you simply enabled the option to use another server URL but are using the same server URL. Let me try that...

Comment: Correct, I just try to connect to my development server in eclipse on my macbook using the custom url. When I don't thick the 'Use Custom URL checkbox' after installing the app, the direct update works.

Comment: Mmm, but I do change the URL, because the default URL, which is filled in after installing the app on the iPad with XCode is incorrect. I don't know where it comes from, but the IP is wrong.

Comment: Do you have several network cards?

Comment: Euhm, I'm using a MacBook Pro.
When I run ifconfig in a console, I can see different network interfaces, but only one has an IP assigned. This is the IP I use as custom URL in the iPad settings. This is also the IP I was using succesfully in WL 6.1 to do direct updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling eclipse resolved the problem. After reinstalling eclipse I also get the correct IP for the custom server URL in the server connectivity settings.

Comment: I just found the root cause of the problem. When I create a new project in WL Studio and deploy it on the iPad I can use direct update. However when I reinstall the app with a new IP things go wrong, the old IP appears in the custom server URL and direct update doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I created a new question with these new findings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060696/direct-update-with-custom-url-not-working-after-ip-change-on-ios?noredirect=1#comment38984766_25060696

Answer (score 1):

I've tried this and I cannot confirm it not working.

1. Added your code snippet to main.js
2. Enabled worklightSettings in application-descriptor.xml
3. Run on Worklight Development Server
4. Open project in Xcode
5. Run
6. Make a change and re-deploy
7. Verify Direct Update is received
8. Quit app
9. Make a change and re-deploy
10. Open myapp settings via Settings.app and enable Custom Server URL. The URL is already pointing to my (same) server
11. Open app
12. Verify Direct Update is received

You mentioned in the comments that once enabling the Custom Server URL option you also need to change the server address to another - I suggest to double-check you are indeed inputting the correct address. Maybe you have several network cards or alike.

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled eclipse and now its working. Now I get the correct ip in the Custom server URL after the first deployment on the iPad. Thanks for your support.