# Direct Update with custom URL not working after IP change on iOS

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm having some issues with direct update on iOS. 
Following scenario describes my problem.

1. Add the code snippet below to main.js
2. Enabled worklightSettings in application-descriptor.xml
3. Run on Worklight Development Server
4. Open project in Xcode via eclipse
5. Run
6. Make a change and re-deploy
7. Verify Direct Update is received
8. Uninstall app
9. Obtain new IP (in my case by restarting my macbook the next day)
10. Open project in Xcode via eclipse
11. Run
12. Open myapp settings via Settings.app and enable Custom Server URL. The URL is pointing to the old IP.
13. Enable Custom Server URL and enter the correct IP
14. Open app
15. Direct Update is not received

Code snippet:

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: onConnectSuccess,
        onFailure: onConnectFailure
    });
}

function onConnectSuccess() {
    WL.Logger.debug("Connect success.");
}

function onConnectFailure() {
    WL.Logger.debug("Connect failed.");
}
```

## EDIT

Try following scenario:

1. create a new app from scratch and deploy it on your iPad
2. verify the custom server URL and test direct update: all is working fine (OK)
3. update the ip on your development machine
4. remove the app from the device and reinstall it
5. verify the custom server URL: the old IP is present (NOK)
6. start the app with the use custom server url unchecked => 'connect success'
7. start the app with the use custom server url checked (don't change ip) => 'connect success'
8. try to access the app in your browser with this ip => doesn't work
9. change the ip and remove the last front slash from the custom server url
10. start the app with the new correct IP (which works in the browser) => 'connect success'
11. change the ip back to the incorrect IP, add the slash and retry => NO 'connect success'

The exact same custom server URL which worked before fails now. When I try a random IP address I also don't get the 'connect success'.

## EDIT

result of ifconfig:

[image: ifconfig]

Comment: Didn't you already ask this... you said you resolved it. Additionally, do you get success or failure in both cases (URLs)?

Comment: Indeed, this was my original question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892458/direct-update-with-custom-url-not-working-on-ios-7-1-2 But now I found out the root problem is the IP change, so I created a new question. I can't reinstall eclipse and set up my project from scratch each time I get a new IP :o) The direct update fails for both URLs when I enable the 'use custom URL' checkbox.

Comment: Not the direct update - do you get "connect success" or "connect failed" before and after the URL change.

Comment: OK; apparently it works when I check the 'use custom URL' checkbox and don't change the IP. When I put the correct IP, I get the following error: [ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: //apps/services/api/HelloWorld/ipad/init    When I remove the front slash at the end of the custom server URL, I get the message an update is available, but if I click update the progress bar doesn't move. The connect success appears in both cases.

Comment: I think that the IP address you think you should use - is the wrong one.

Comment: I'm 100% sure I use the correct IP. I verified this in the browser. I think the old IP gets cached somewhere and this breaks the direct update. I'll edit my question with another scenario to indicate this.

Comment: Run in CMD ipconfig or ifconfig (if on Mac) and check how many addresses you get. Sometimes the wrong IP may be attached to the server. This is mentioned when you add a project (see in the Eclipse console), where it provides instructions how to use the correct IP address.

Comment: okay, so I see there 2 addresses starting with 172.x.x.x; which do you use and which do you get in the app?

Comment: I use 172.17.22.35. In the app I get the old IP address, which isn't displayed in the ifconfig. The old IP address is the IP address I got when I first installed the app, so the problem was indeed the cache in XCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a project in Worklight Studio, the following warning message is outputted:

> FWLPL0010W: The current server configuration is set to "localhost".
>   Therefore the Worklight build uses the primary IP address of this 
>   computer (192.168.1.100) instead. It is recommended to set the server
>   configuration to use the fully qualified hostname or IP address  of
>   this computer. To configure the setting, in the "Servers" view
>   double-click the Worklight Development Server entry and edit the "Host
>   name" field.

In the comments you say the wrong IP address is used, so try and change the default IP address  that Worklight Studio selects by following the above instructions. The address you will set will be used as the server address, as well as be used in the application (the address that you see in the app settings page).

To make sure the settings page is fully 'refreshed':

- Delete the app from the device/simulator
- When opening the project in Xcode, first select Clean and then Run (because Xcode tends to keep the Settings.bundle file cached)

Comment: Command-Option-Shift-K to clean the project in Xcode did the job. Thanks for your support and patience :o)